# Using R to extract mini series from a big series with visible breaks (when plotted)

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

Here is my data:

```
data1 <- c(726, 718, 699, 737, 743, 734, 726, 722, 715, 714, 752, 750, 
749, 746, 743, 734, 725, 717, 717, 708, 756, 753, 752, 746, 744, 
740, 737, 732, 728, 728, 720, 720, 714, 703, 702, 697, 758, 753, 
753, 746, 743, 734, 720, 706, 697, 761, 744, 749, 741, 738, 738, 
732, 725, 720, 712, 782, 778, 776, 773, 772, 770, 770, 769, 769, 
766, 763, 763, 756, 755, 753, 750, 749, 746, 737, 723, 711, 702, 
685, 782, 779, 778, 778, 776, 776, 775, 772, 770, 770, 766, 763, 
761, 756, 752, 738, 735, 729, 715)
```

This gives the plot using `plot(data1)` as:

[image]

How can I segregate the **eight** separate trends using R? I can use `identify(data1)` and mark them (the shifts) manually and use the indexes to segregate them but it would not be possible in my case since I am dealing with many of these kinds of plots. I want to extract the separate lines programmatically. Please let me know if there is statistical technique (time series and so on) which identifies the change in trends and tags and returns the **eight** series.

**EDIT**

I should make it clear that the number of series in the whole data-set need to be identified. The number of series in the sample data happens to be eight. But I will not know this in each case unless I plot the data and identify the breaks manually.

Comment: Identifying "manually" is not good enough. You need to make an explicit statement about what it takes to separate a cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Kiril is right on here ( +1 ).  This is a substantial area of research/knowledge, sometimes called Change Point or Break Point Analysis.  Relevant R packages include `strucchange`  `changepoint`, as mentioned by Kiril, and `bcp`.

`strucchange`'s `breakpoints()` uses least squares regression to estimate the
locations of changes when told how many changes there are (which is not helpful here.)

`changepoint` has several algorithms, as Kiril said, including Scott and Knott's Binary Segmentation, Auger and Lawrence's Segment Neighbourhoods, and Killick et al's Pruned Exact Linear Time (PELT) algorithm.  Its a great package, but my very limited experience is that these functions will require a bunch of tuning (which is worth doing).

For important tasks, we would want to leverage our knowledge of the data to make more detailed model(s) and, ultimately, combine several methods into an ensemble classifier.

But for simple click and go, you could use `bcp` which uses an MCMC-based approximation of Barry and Hartigan's Bayes procedure:

```
library(bcp)
changefit <- bcp(data1)
plot(changefit)
```

[image]

One way to segregate the groups would be to pick a posterior probability threshold and `split()` the data based on it:

```
data2 <- data.frame(data=data1, prob = changefit$posterior.prob)
threshold <- 0.90
split(data2,c(0, cumsum( ifelse (data2$prob > threshold, 1, 0))))
#split will warn about unequal lengths
```

Comment: Can you please see why this is not working well? `source('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/55687041/SO_13735049.r')`

Comment: I was (secretly) afraid of that. :-) I think I would use diff() rather than the raw data:  https://gist.github.com/4230765

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your answer. I am trying to get the best out of your good efforts

Comment: That sounds like you're still having issues. Please let me know how I can clarify or help further.

Comment: Ironically, as you also stated on your github page, the best method is the `bigdiffs` one. Of course, the trick is to come up with the best threshold for it.

Answer (score 2):

You do have one pair where it's not monotonic and need to make sur that the "upstroke" is greater than a threshold.

```
labs=factor( c(0, cumsum( data1[-1] - data1[-length(data1)] > 7 )), 
             labels=letters[1:8])
plot(data1, pch=as.character(labs) )
```

[image]

Need automatic calculation of number of cycles? You could use the length of:

```
unique (factor( c(0, cumsum( data1[-1] - data1[-length(data1)] > 7 )) ))
```

... in this case. but it does require being willing to accept breaks defined by any upstroke greater than 6. (Or you can pick 15, or whatever makes sense from the underlying science.)

Comment: Thanks DWin. I actually need to find the number of series programatically. When I said **eight** series. It was for this particular series only and I would not know this for other series.

Comment: In order to specify the problem you need to clarify what upward movement is required to start a new cycle. At the moment I used the maximum upstroke with a cycle _because_ you said there were 8 cycles. You need to make explicit what constitutes "reset".

Answer (score 2):

OK, there is a statistical technique which will solve your problem. If I understood correctly, what you want to do is in fact to detect the places where the statistical properties of your data change, i.e. to detect different behaviors. This is done by a technique called 'changepoint detection', and R has pretty good package for this called '[changepoint](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/)'. It uses linear algorithms for doing the calculations which are pretty new. If I am not mistaken, I believe the PELT algorithm which is used here is pretty good and it is invented about two years ago, so it is pretty modern approach. Take a look at the function 'cpt.meanvar' which will detect the changes that are made both in the mean and the variance of your data. It is pretty neat and if you are patient enough - you can figure out a way that will be automatic and good enough for detecting changes in all data that you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a density based cluster algorithem like `dbscan` in the `fpc` package.